# "Updating VMware Tools for Linux" spins forever

Tags: vmware-player, vmware-tools

I installed Ubuntu 11.04 using VMware Player 3.1.4 inside Ubuntu 10.10

When first booting on the ISO image I was asked if I wanted to download the VMware Tools for Linux and I accepted. It downloaded for a few minutes, and then it has been "updating" for an hour already. Even shutting down the VM does not stop it.

If I try to exit VMware, I am told:

```
Cannot exit while still downloading. Cancel all downloads and try again." but the dialog's Cancel button is greyed out.
```

[image: screenshot]

Nothing special in `vmware.log`
I ended up killing VMware Player.

A few days after I restarted it, it asked about the VMware Tools again, I accepted again, and same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. It seems to hang while trying to ask you for your password to authorize the update. For some reason it needs root to have a password. I simply 'passwd root' and 'kill -9'ed the process running 'vmware-gksu' then tried again. And voila: after the download a window popped up and asked me for my password.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run it from console and observe the output. There is probably some interactive part.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when fingerprint auth is enabled. If you touch thew fingerprint right after it enters `pending` state, it would either proceed or ask for password if your fingerprint isn't recognized.

Comment: I can't try now but I indeed had fingerprint auth enabled at that time, so it could well be that!